# Java8 Lambda Function apply alternative syntax

Tags: lambda, java-8

When using lambda function variable, is there an alternative to invoking function with `apply`.

```
Function<String, String> mesgFunction =  (name) -> "Property "+ name +" is not set in the environment";
Optional.ofNullable(System.getProperty("A")).orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException(mesgFunction.apply("A")));
Optional.ofNullable(System.getProperty("B")).orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException(mesgFunction.apply("B")));
```

Is there a shorter syntax to `mesgFunction.apply("A")`. I tried `mesgFunction("A")` which complained that the method does not exist. Am I missing something? Isn't there a shorter alternative?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a good use case for a lambda.  Is this what you're really trying to do?  Why not just put everything on the right side of the `->` in the `println` method directly?

Comment: There's hope since Scala actually does that. So maybe in a future release we get the shorthand version of methods calls on lambdas.

Answer (score 4):

No, the fact that an interface is a functional interface doesn’t allow any alternative calling syntax; it’s methods are invoked like any other interface method.

But you can just factor out more of the common code to shorten the repeated code

```
Function<String, Supplier<IllegalArgumentException>> f = name ->
    () -> new IllegalArgumentException("Property "+name+" is not set in the environment");
String valueA = Optional.of("A").map(System::getProperty).orElseThrow(f.apply("A"));
String valueB = Optional.of("B").map(System::getProperty).orElseThrow(f.apply("B"));
```

however, this still has no advantage over a conventional

```
public static String getRequiredProperty(String name) {
    String value = System.getProperty(name);
    if (value == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Property "+name+" is not set in the environment");
    }

    return value;
}
```

```
String valueA = getRequiredProperty("A");
String valueB = getRequiredProperty("B");
```

which has the advantage of having no code duplication (esp. regarding the constants `"A"` and `"B"`), thus less room for accidental inconsistencies.

Comment: Why not just have `Function<String, String> getRequiredProperty = (name) -> Optional.ofNullable(System.getProperty(name)).orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Property "+ name +" is not set in the environment"));`? Then the invocation simply becomes `String valueA = getRequiredProperty.apply("A")`.

Comment: Say yourself… what’s the advantage of saying `getRequiredProperty.apply("A")` over `getRequiredProperty("A")`?

Comment: For your first answer, The duplication of code is reduced by eliminating the need to specify the property name twice.

Comment: Yes, it’s better than your original code, but it still has no advantage over an ordinary method.

Comment: @Holger: An advantage of using a Function over a method could be the exposure of your code. Even if you make a method private, it is still callable by reflection. Putting the function inline makes it impossible to call from everywhere else.

Comment: @JacobvanLingen the body of a lambda expression ends up in a `private` method of the owner class. You’d need a bit of guesswork or heuristic to find the right method when multiple functions with the same signature exist, but it’s still possible to invoke it via Reflection.

Comment: Awesome, never knew that was the actual implementation. Guess I need to start reading byte code :P. Then, I stand corrected, there a no real advantages except coding style preferences.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no alternative like that. `apply()` is "just" a method of the `Function` interface, so that method must be called. There is no syntactic sugar to make that more concise.